# Dataplex querying data storage entity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-dataplex

We have a Dataplex instance and I've ingested there some data and I've tried to query that data with Dataplex Workbench.
So as a result I'm able to see my entity in the Workbench list, can see my schema but when I do the select it returns me just the partition timestamp. It repeats same value same amount of time as there is records in the file.
My query is pretty simple:

```
select * from my_test_zone.gcs_assetr limit 10;
```

the result is:

[image]

How can I select the data from there?

Answer (score 0):

After a day of investigation I've found that Dataplex requires schema to be in lowercase.